# How to use long data type in Java?

Tags: java, types, long-integer

I have to use quite a big number - 600851475143; as we all know, I have to use long data type but when I try to initialize like: `long number = 600851475143` I get an error:

> The literal 600851475143 of type int is out of range.

It seems that I don't know how to use long data type correctly.

Comment: That number looks familiar... http://projecteuler.net/ :D

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
long number = 600851475143L
```

Use "L" to make it as long type

Comment: Hi, could you add further what the L is and how we can use it in future number declaration? Thanks

Comment: @DeanMeehan, L or l represents "long" type. So whenever you want to declare a number explicitly to long type, you must add "l" to the number. if you are assigning the data directly, you need to add "l" to make it long or if the data is assigned during runtime, the JVM will automatically convert the data type, which you don't need to worry

Comment: Thanks :) ..and is this the same for byte etc?

Comment: @DeanMeehan, nope. You can check Java documents for that :)

Comment: @Reddy Shouldn't you be using `l` instead of `L`? I guess it's a personal preference but I have met many programmers who think `L` would create a `Long`.

Answer (score 6):

**Use "L" to make it as long type. By default all integer type variable(byte,int,long) is "int"**

```
long num=600851475143L;
```

or

```
long num=600851475143l; // small 'L'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
 long number = 600851475143L;
```